# How to use Laravel Markdown in View blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

My primary goal was to grab the raw html output of the view file to send to an external API (Zoho) to process the email.

I have a file in `/resources/views/emails/welcome.blade.php` (there is no Mailable class for that file)

and I have this code below which pulls the raw html of the file ( using `view()->render()` )

```
$to = [
    'user_name' => 'Test',
    'email' => 'xxx@email.com'
];

$mail = [
    'to' => $to
    'lines' => ['Test 1', 'Test 2']
];

$data = [
    'to' => [$to],
    'mail_format' => 'html',
    'content' => view('emails.welcome', compact('mail'))->render()
];

$payload = $this->payload( [$data] );
```

However, I want to use markdown on the `welcome.blade.php`, I tried using the `<x-mail:message>` I've seen on other email template like the code below, but its throwing an error **`No hint path defined for [mail].`**

```
<x-mail::message>
# Hi {{ $mail[to]['user_name'] }}

{{-- Lines --}}
@foreach ($mail['lines'] as $line)
{!! $line !!}

@endforeach

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
</x-mail::message>
```

and if I add the content directly in the file, the markdown tagging does not work

appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, I tried to make the Markdown work on my local and it works, can you test this out (don't forget to put `use Illuminate\Mail\Markdown` at the top of your class):

```
use Illuminate\Mail\Markdown;

...

$to = [
    'user_name' => 'Test',
    'email' => 'xxx@email.com'
];

$mail = [
    'to' => $to
    'lines' => ['Test 1', 'Test 2']
];

$markdown = app(Markdown::class);

$data = [
    'to' => [$to],
    'mail_format' => 'html',
    'content' => $markdown->render('emails.welcome', compact('mail'))->toHtml()
];

$payload = $this->payload( [$data] );
```